# Select element of collection by highest value of specific attribute

Tags: select, collections, orientdb

I have several documents stored in my database with the following format:

```
{
    "text": "foo",
    "items": [{
        "num": 1,
        "value": 1.1
    }, {
        "num": 42,
        "value": 3.14
    }]
}

{
    "text": "bar",
    "items": [{
        "num": 3,
        "value": 5.0
    }]
}
```

I want to retrieve from each document the "text" and the "value" of the item with the highest "num". So in this example my result would be:

```
{
    "text": "foo",
    "value": 3.14
}

{
    "text": "bar",
    "value": 5.0
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem with OrientDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with these records

[image]

and I used this query

```
select rid,items.num as num,items.value as value from (
select @rid,items,$a[0].max as max from test 
let $a=(select max(items.num) as max from $parent.$current)
unwind items
)
where items.num=max
```

I got

[image]

Best regards,
Alessandro